# list Maven parent projects

Tags: maven-3

I can get the artifactId of a single project:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout
```

But now I have a multi-module project with ~500 modules. I want to build one with

```
mvn -pl :<artifactId> install
```

How do I display a list of available project artifactIds without a tonne of text?

Answer (score 0):

A made an alias. Pre-clean seems like the fastest phase to use.

```
mvn pre-clean -B $@ | sed -nr 's/.+< ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*) >.+/\1/p' | sort
```

The extra arguments are so you can activate a profile after discovering them with

```
mvn help:all-profiles -B | grep "Profile Id" | sort -u | grep -E "true|$"
```